# How to show whitespace as dots in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Whitespace can be rendered as dots in Pycharm.

[image: Grey dots showing spaces in Pycharm: ....name.=.'Montreal']

How can I do the same in Jupyter Notebook?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my search, there's no native way to do it in Jupyter Notebook.

But you can use an addon to make this work in Jupyterlab's Codemirror instance.

---

How to Install in Codemirror:

```bash
bower i cm-show-invisibles --save # or
npm i cm-show-invisibles --save
```

How to use:

```js
const cm = CodeMirror(document.body, {
    showInvisibles: true,
    maxInvisibles: 16 // optional
});
```

P.S. This plug-in can only be used on Jupyterlab's Codemirror instance, not on Jupyter Notebook.

Relevant:

- Codemirror: [codemirror.net](https://codemirror.net/)
- Addon project github: [github.com/.../cm-showinvisibles](https://github.com/coderaiser/cm-show-invisibles)
- Source: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/1281